# Why is my debug data unformatted?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

`var_dump` and `print_r` are displayed are not formatted when using Laravel 4. How do I format the data to be more readable?

Comment: I guess you have already looked in http://doc.laravelbook.com/errors/ ?

Comment: Install xdebug. Everything will be pretty then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add Kint to your composer.json by running this on the command line:

```
composer require raveren/kint "dev-master"
```

And then try it:

```
dd( new Controller );
```

You should see this:

[image]

Better, huh?

Comment: Nothing, just that. Are you having trouble? There's a known tiny issue between it and Laravel 4, but not too difficult to fix: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1472.

Comment: I'm a real noob at composer, I have a small request, could you re-edit your question to include the stable branch of kint, as I refer to your answer from the documentation of kint:
http://raveren.github.io/kint/#integration Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using dd() in the current version of laravel (4.0.10) has no effect. Probably because dd() is built into laravel now. Using d() applied Kint properly.

Comment: This is a Laravel problem. It should not create a dd() if there's already one around. Unfortunately this was already discussed in a Laravel issue but the most we got from developers was: delete your vendors and composer install again, sometimes it works.

Comment: Is there a way to disable Kint in Laravel for production environments?

Answer (score 2):

Use kint

we use should  **s()** instead of **print_r()**

use should **d()** instead of **var_dump()**

ex: 
sd($arr); like same print_r($arr); die();

Ref: http://raveren.github.io/kint/#configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **pre** tag to format align your answear
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp