# How to display a readable array - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, function, laravel, readable

After I write:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    dd(User::all());
});
```

And after I refresh the browser I get an unreadable array. Is there a way to get that array in a readable format?

Comment: SUrround your array output with `<pre>ARRAY_DUMP_CODE</pre>` tags

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`dd()` dumps the variable and ends the execution of the script <sup>(1)</sup>, so surrounding it with `<pre>` tags will leave it broken. Just use good ol' `var_dump()` (or `print_r()` if you know it's an array)

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump(User::all());
    echo '</pre>';
    //exit;  <--if you want
});
```

**Update:**

I think you could format down what's shown by having Laravel convert the model object to array:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    echo '<pre>';
    $user = User::where('person_id', '=', 1);
    var_dump($user->toArray()); // <---- or toJson()
    echo '</pre>';
    //exit;  <--if you want
});
```

---

(1) For the record, this is the implementation of dd():

```
function dd()
{
    array_map(function($x) { var_dump($x); }, func_get_args()); die;
}
```

Comment: This gives indeed a readable array :) Another problem is that it gives a very large array and the information I need is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Well, what information do you want? You could dump other methods to filter down to what you actually need. User::all() returns the whole object indeed

Comment: I just want the array of the User object. I gave this in my route: User::find(6)->where('person_id' == 1) and the page gives me an array that begins with "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder Object
(..." I have to scroll al the way down to get the array of the User object.

Comment: Try having Lravel convert to array, see updated answer

Comment: I think the where() syntax was inaccurate. I almost never use Eloquent, I have to admit (always prefer the Query Builder))

Comment: You could be right, because when I give var_dump(User::all()); it only gives me the User object and not the additional information.

Comment: use dump as it wont exit the code after printing

Answer (score 30):

actually a much easier way to get a readable array of what you (probably) want to see, is instead of using

```
dd($users);
```

or

```
dd(User::all());
```

use this

```
dd($users->toArray());
```

or

```
 dd(User::all()->toArray());
```

which is a lot nicer to debug with.

EDIT - additional, this also works nicely in your views / templates
so if you pass the get all users to your template, you can then dump it into your blade template

```
{{ dd($users->toArray()) }}
```

Comment: This is the right (and better) way to do it in Laravel.

Comment: See Flame's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734167/display-laravels-dd-results-without-die-d-dump-in-blade#comment105617268_59734253

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try kint: composer require raveren/kint "dev-master"
More information: [Why is my debug data unformatted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009465/why-is-my-debug-data-unformatted/17010520#17010520)

Answer (score 2):

For everyone still searching for a nice way to achieve this, the recommended way is the `dump()` function from `symfony/var-dumper`.

It is added to documentation since version 5.2: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-dd

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code on view.blade.
{{var_dump($animales)}}

Comment: Explain what you're suggesting with a bit more.detail

Answer (score 1):

as suggested, you can use 'die and dump' such as  
  
`dd($var)` 
  
or only 'dump', without dying,  
 
`dump($var)`

Answer (score 1):

Weird that nobody pointed out to Symfony VarDumper, simply do:

```
\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_dump` or `print_r` functions on Blade themplate via Controller functions :

```
class myController{

   public function showView(){
     return view('myView',["myController"=>$this]);
   }
   public function myprint($obj){
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($obj);
     echo "</pre>";
   }
}
```

And use your blade themplate :

```
$myController->myprint($users);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a helper `da()` to Laravel which in fact works as an alias for `dd($object->toArray())`

Here is the Gist: https://gist.github.com/TommyZG/0505eb331f240a6324b0527bc588769c