# Script execution / foreach() loop stops when I call Laravel's dd() function

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, dump, dd

When I call `dd()` (die and dump) like `dd($user->friends());` I only get the output from the first record in the collection.

When I try to do something like:

```
foreach($user->friends() as $friend) {
    dd($friend);
}
```

This is what I get :

```
User {#189 ▼
  #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:7 [▶]
  #hidden: array:3 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
  #original: array:13 [▶]
  #relations: array:1 [▶]
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

But when I dump out the collection without looping, I can see multiple records.

```
Collection {#184 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => User {#189 ▼
      #table: "users"
      #fillable: array:7 [▶]
      #hidden: array:3 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:11 [▶]
      #original: array:13 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => User {#190 ▼
      #table: "users"
      #fillable: array:7 [▶]
      #hidden: array:3 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:11 [▶]
      #original: array:13 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

I want it to loop through all the users not just the first one. Is there a reason it is doing this. Am I doing the foreach wrong or does it have something to do with the collection?

Comment: Topically related: [How to display a readable array - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20771239/2943403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do your `foreach`, you're only seeing one entry because of the `dd()`. Remember, it is "dump and die", so on the very first iteration, you're dumping the record and then dying.

Try this out:

```
foreach($user->friends() as $friend) {
    dump($friend);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to treat it as an array, use toArray on the collection first. Eg:

```
$friends = $user->friends()->toArray();
foreach($friends as $friend){
 ...some stuff...
}
```

Otherwise, use the features of the laravel collection as per the docs here:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections

Comment: That pushed it to an array , but for some reason if I do that I still only get one user back.
     $friends = $user->friends()->toArray();
    foreach($friends as $friend){
      dd($friend);
    }

Comment: I tried to make that look nice sorry it does not , I basically did what you said and inside the foreach dd($friend) and still am getting one user back, but I am getting an array back now.

Comment: Try it this way instead and see if it works. 
$friends = $user->friends->toArray();
Otherwise, are you sure you have more than 1 friend associated with the user?

Comment: Oh, duh.....sorry, I'm a bit rusty with Laravel. Ignore my previous comment. I think this is what you need:  $user->friends->all()->asArray().

Comment: Yes if you look at the original post I am basically getting that except without the collection part now. I just have an array with two users at 0 => user, and 1 => user. I looked at the collections and I can do $user->friends()->count() and I receive 2.

Comment: So this is kind of a funny error I got with I did the all()->asArray . Call to a member function asArray() on array. But when I do the friends()->toArray it works just fine.

Comment: None of this `toArray()` stuff is needed. Collections are traversable, so they work in `foreach` natively. The issue is that `dd()` is "dump and die", emphasis on the "die" part. You'll hit the first iteration, and then die.