# Display Laravel's dd() results without die -> d(), dump() in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, dump, dd

I want to display the content of my session with the same style that the dd() function.

I try to do this :

```
<div>
    {!! dump(session()->all()) !!}
</div>
```

And i get this error :

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Array to string conversion
```

I don't understand why, because dump() should be able to display an array, no ?

How can i manage this ?
Thanks

Comment: in blade there are @dump() and @dd()

Comment: dd is `dump and die`.  This should be used for debugging not to display results

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<?php dump(session()->all()) ?>
```

This is how you can display array in blade.

The `{ }` are used to `echo` results (simple strings, integers etc etc) but as you know not suitable for arrays.

Comment: in addition you're basically double echo'ing when you do `{{ dump() }}`, since dump itself already outputs.